# Existance of compile-time computation that can get compilers into endless loop

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, compile-time

Does there exist such kind of compile-time computation that can get compilers into endless loop?

May the endless loop not consume increasing memory? Or it may stop for the lack of memory.

Comment: Yes. Compile time computation has exactly the same issues as run-time computation.

Answer (score 5):

There are infinite loops just like in run-time, however unlike run-time, the compiler will stop after enough iterations. Here's an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<int i>
struct loop {
    // this will just keep referencing itself
    static constexpr int val = loop<i + 1>::val;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << loop<0>::val << std::endl;
}
```

The compiler gives the following error message:

```
fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900
```